# Dovecot process limits

Tags: freebsd, dovecot

Sometimes my dovecot log return:

`service(imap-login): process_limit (512) reached, client connections are being dropped`

I can increase `process_limit` in dovecot config file, but i dont understand, how will it affect the system.
How to diagnose why process limit is too high? I have around 50 users in my postfix+dovecot+roundcube system.

My configuration:

- FreeBSD 10.0-stable
- Postfix 2.10
- Dovecot 2.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dovecot have two modes for login processes.

First is called `secure mode` when each client is connected via its own process.

Second is called `performance mode` when single process serve all the clients.

In fact `performance mode` is not so insecure, but rather `secure mode` is paranoid.

You have to set desired mode in the config:

```
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port        = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port        = 993
    ssl         = yes
  }
# service_count = 0 # Performance mode
  service_count = 1 # Secure mode
  process_min_avail = 1
}
```

In my case performance mode serve to 1k+ users.