# Why iterating over all java mail user's folders very slow?

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-mail, imap, dovecot

```
   Properties props = System.getProperties();
   props.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout",5000);
   Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
   Store store = session.getStore("imap");
   for(50K users){

        //login,password changed in loop  
        String[] folders = {"inbox", "f1", "f2", "f3", "spam"};
        store.connect(serverAddress, login + emailSuffix, password);
        for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
                    Folder x = store.getFolder(folders[i]);
                    x.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                    System.out.println("folder " + folders[i] + " of " + login);
                    x.getUnreadMessageCount();
                    x.close(false);
        }
        store.close();
    }
```

I'm using same store for all connections, changed `service_count` in dovecot according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30193078/2104560) in order to improve imap-dovecot performance but I see only first iteration and after that code hangs or does next system.out after long time.

Actually, I need to grab all old messages of all users + count all unread messages as I want to migrate from pure Java Mail to some custom format. I didn;t manage even to just iterate over all users and folders for each user because even simple store.connect hangs after 1-st iteration!

I personally think that bottleneck is my dovecot config, but it uses default limits (1000 connections) which looks good.

My I somehow improve my dovecot or connect my store only once for all users or somehow fetch all messages of all users and unreadMessagesCount of all users in other way?

PS. The only alternative to programmatic way is some bash script in maildir which whill read each message from file system and pass it to some rest which converts to my custom format) but it much more harder than Java it's too difficult to parse smptp, parse `seen` flags from file name and so on.

**UPDATE**

I found apache commons net imapclient which works very fast.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My code is the following

```
IMAPClient client = new IMAPClient();
client.connect("localhost");
for(50K users){
    client.login(login + emailSuffix, password);
    for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(client.select("INBOX"); //prints true, it's ok
    }
}
```

1. Looks like it connects faster than java mailapi because it may
   **connect once to host** and after that **login for each user**. May I somehow repeat such behavior in JavaMail API?
2. How may I grab messages with apache commons client? All methods return boolean or void, so it's looks like just server checking library am I right? Is it possible to somehow get useful info from imapclient?

Comment: I don't know Javamail, but if you're iterating through 50k users synchronously, connecting 50k times,  and calling sysout at least 50k times, it's going to be really slow. This should be multi-threaded.

Comment: If it becomes slow when opening the second folder for the first user, or the first folder for the second user, then obviously this has nothing to do with the number of users. (I wasn't sure what you meant by "first iteration".)  If it's slow making the first connect call, it's probably either the name service being slow returning the IP address for the server's host name, or the server being slow to authenticate the user.  You can watch the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) in real time to see which protocol operation is slow.

Comment: @BillShannon, same question [was asked](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2153480?start=0&tstart=0) on oracle forums and you gave an answer that all problems in server side. Did you mean dovecot poor configuration? Now I'm trying just to store.connect and dissconnect in loop, without opening folders and I see that some users connects in 10-20 milliseconds and rarely I see 1 minute connect time. Should I still configure my dovecot or I may somehow improve my Javamail code?

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem in the server, but I don't know if it's something you can solve by changing the configuration.  You might get more help on the [dovecot mailing list](http://www.dovecot.org/mailinglists.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem by simple iterating over file system (I have maildir format).

**I guess Java Mail API makes new dovecot auth for each user in `store.connect` while it should just connect once (consume dovecot auth) and after that login for each user (consume dovecot imap-login).** That's why I waited 1 minute for each iteration - it's std idle for auth process in dovecot config. I'm not sure but looks so.

**Apache lib [works fast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38121397/2104560) but it's just testing library** for pinging server, checking connection and other imap operations. It returns boolean result about operations but not useful information(

Comment: IMAP in general does not allow you to reauthenticate an existing connection.

Comment: @Max, how apache commons managed to connect 50K times faster then other approaches taking to account same dovecot configs? Anyway, filesystem-maildir scan easisest approach)