# How get useful mail info with commons ImapClient? Not just boolean status but real info?

Tags: java, imap, apache-commons

My maven is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My code is the following

```
IMAPClient client = new IMAPClient();
client.connect("localhost");
for(50K users){
    client.login(login + emailSuffix, password);
    for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(client.select("INOX"); //prints true, it's ok
    }
}
```

How may I grab messages with apache commons client? All methods return boolean or void, so it's looks like just server checking library am I right? **Is it possible to somehow get useful info from imapclient?** I mean number of unread messages, Message objects (content+headers+sibject) by some term and so on.

P.S. Java Mail api of course has all functions I need but it very slow for using it in 50K loop (My efforts on Java Mail API described on [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991025/why-iterating-over-all-java-mail-users-folders-very-slow). Commons is much more faster in connection but couldn't give useful info(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem by simple iterating over file system (I have maildir format). **I guess Java Mail API makes new dovecot auth for each user in `store.connect` while it should just connect once (consume dovecot auth) and after that login for each user (consume dovecot imap-login)**. That's why I waited 1 minute for each iteration - it's std idle for auth process in dovecot config. I'm not sure but looks so.

Apache lib works fast but **it's just testing library for pinging server**, checking connection and other imap operations. It returns boolean result about operations but not useful information(